# Is there a way that you can use the "if" branch to check whether a USB stick is connected?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Is there a way like that you can use the "if" branch to check whether a USB-Stick is connected? And if the stick is not connected, a message should then be issued.

Something like:

```
if [-e /sdb1]
then
cp /home/backup/* /sdb1
rm -r /home/backup/*
echo "your files are successfully transferred."
else
echo "please be sure, if your USB-Stick is connected"
fi
```

Comment: `[` is a command.  `[-e` is (most likely) not. It is entirely possible that you have a function defined named `[-e`, or a file in your PATH named `[-e`, but not likely.

Answer (score 0):

No, the mount point exists whether or not a USB device is connected.

Something like this **should** suffice:

```
if [[ $(df | grep "/sdb1") && -d /sdb1 && -w /sdb1 ]]
```

That is **if**, of course, you have actually created the directory `/sdb1/`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `findmnt` utility (installed by default on RH and Ubuntu, at least)

```
findmnt /backup
echo $?
1
```

Return of 1 means not mounted.

Here is some sample code using it with an if statment

```
findmnt /backup >/dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    echo "It's mounted all right"
else
    r=$(( RANDOM % 4 ))
    echo "USB is not mounted."
    case $r in
        0) echo "Check the couch cushions."
           ;;
        1) echo "I think I saw it in the kitchen."
           ;;
        2) echo "Sign up for Prime and get free shipping!"
           ;;
        3) echo "The dog ate it."
           ;;
    esac
fi
```

Comment: It's much cleaner to write `if findmnt ...; then ...; else ...; fi`.  Avoid explicitly checking `$?` when possible.